# Outlook 2013: Adding button to reading pane?

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-2013

Is it possible to add a custom button to Outlook 2013 reading pane - next to "FORWARD" (where the red arrow points)...

[image]

?

Comment: Hi MojoDK. Did you find out?

Comment: Hi - nope, it seams like it's not possible.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I didn't find anything on my side either.

Answer (score 0):

These are standard buttons in reading button and you can't alter or add to it.